# Android Studio 3.2 alpha 17 Build failed with error: Android resource linking failed

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin, aapt2

```
    Android resource linking failed
    Output:  /Users/$USER/$PROJECT_DIR/app/src/main/res/layout/main_fragment.xml:21: 
        error: resource drawable/ic_search_24dp 
        (aka $PACKAGE_NAME:drawable/ic_search_24dp) not found.

        /Users/$USER/$PROJECT_DIR/app/src/main/res/layout/list_item.xml:20:
        error: resource drawable/ic_send 
        (aka $PACKAGE_NAME:drawable/ic_send) not found.


    error: failed linking file resources.

    Command: /Users/$USER/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-
    3.2.0-alpha17-4804415-osx.jar/58236ee12e68217ae9214b5ecae3ebc4/aapt2
    3.2.0-alpha17-4804415-osx/aapt2 link -I\

    /Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-27/android.jar\
    --manifest\

    /Users/$USER/$PROJECT_DIR/app/build/intermediates
    /merged_manifests/debug/processDebugManifest/merged/AndroidManifest.xml\-o\

    /Users/$USER/$PROJECT_DIR/app/build/intermediates
    /processed_res/debug/processDebugResources/out/resources-debug.ap_\-R\

    @/Users/$USER/$PROJECT_DIR/app/build/intermediates

    /incremental/processDebugResources/resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\--auto-add-overlay\--java\
/Users/$USER/$PROJECT_DIR/app/build
/generated/not_namespaced_r_class_sources/debug/processDebugResources/r\
                    --custom-package\
                    $PACKAGE_NAME\
                    -0\
                    apk\
                    --output-text-symbols\
                    /Users/$USER/$PROJECT_DIR/app/build/intermediates/symbols/debug/R.txt\
                    --no-version-vectors
     Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-alpha17-4804415-osx Daemon #0
```

Studio Build:

- Version of Gradle Plugin: 4.6
- Version of Android plugin: 3.2.0-alpha17
- Compile SDK version: API 27: Android 8.1 (Oreo)

dependencies maybe related

- ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.41'
- ext.support_library_version = '27.1.1'
- ext.glide_version = '4.0.0-RC0'

Steps to Reproduce:

1- Build a project that has some vector-drawables under the drawable folder

it points out that  ic_send and ic_search_24dp are not found although they exist.

Comment: Have you tried to use Android 28? And download latest Build Tools and Android Platform from SDK Manager. And try to rebuild project.

Comment: do you solved this problem?

Comment: @GeorgiyChebotarev No, I couldn't resolve it.

Comment: @YosiPramajaya I did but to no avail.

Comment: What about other drawable resources. Can your project find it? Or just those 2?

Comment: it can't find any vector drawables, it works fine with pngs.

Comment: What is the folder in which the vector drawables are located in? If you open the file `/Users/$USER/$PROJECT_DIR/app/build/intermediates/incremental/processDebugResources/resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt` does it contain a file path containing `ic_search_24dp`?

Comment: the vector derawables are located in /Users/$USER/$PROJECT_DIR/app/src/main/res/drawable

Comment: I just renamed the drawable files (added an arbitrary prefix, ex: `ic_search.xml` has become `twitter_ic_search.xml` )and did clean then Build, and the errors went away and now everything is working.

Comment: I tried to create a new project to reproduce the issue but the issue was not curring, So I don't know exactly what is the root cause, However, I guess It was due to the incremental build since it was occurring on that project only.